# FIX messages are being ‘truncated’ when requesting the ICE TradeCaptureReport

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj, ice

The FIX messages are being ‘truncated’ when requesting the ICE TradeCaptureReport message. This results in the fact that we are not consuming the ‘repeating groups’ of the message (like parties, leg details).

We haven't used any data dictionary. Any solution to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is simple: use the data dictionary.

Otherwise the FIX engine does not know how to parse repeating groups. It needs to know the delimiter tag to know where one instance of a repeating group starts.

Here is an explanation (you probably can ignore the code examples): https://ref.onixs.biz/cpp-fix-engine-guide/group__fix-protocol-repeating-group.html